# white page after entering "payment methods"

Tags: magento-2.1

I installed the extension: "delete order's". when it comes to this module everything works as it should be, so I do not know if it has anything to do with it.

I go to `stores ---> configuration  ---> Sales  and try to config "payment methods"`then  I get a white page.

Does anyone know what can be the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Put the `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` in `index.php` and check the error

Comment: Check var/log inner files and var/log/nginx or apache2 error.log

Comment: When I put line ini_set('display_errors', 1 in index.php the whole page has stopped loading (no work). 404 error. I had to replace the index.php file with the original one back